# Created a small utility class for progress dialog

Tags: java, android

```
public class ProgressDialogUtils {

    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /*
    * Create an progaress dialog instance
     * @param Context contex
     * @Title title of String
     *
    * */
    public static ProgressDialog createProgressDialoge(Context context, String title) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage(title);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        return progressDialog;
    }

    /*
    * It dimiss progress dialoge if already visible
    *
    * */
    public static void dissmisProgress() {
        if (progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Show a progress dialoge
     */

    public static void showProgress() {
        if (progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.show();
    }


}
```

Here I have added a static progress dialog object and I am going to use this object in many class. 
Would you please suggest me to make this more facilitate ?

Any help will highly appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean by "make this more facilitate?"

Comment: I mean easily pass a value for title,context etc. and I would like to use this utility at more on my side project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do not repeat code

Your methods `showProgress` and `dissmisProgress()` simply delegate the call to the `ProgressDialog` instance it currently knows.

What happens if you have something like that:

```
class SomeClass{
  private void theMainMethod(){
     aMethod();
     anotherMethod();
     ProgressDialogUtils.dissmisProgress(); // you cannot close both!
  }
  private void aMethod(){
    ProgressDialogUtils.createProgressDialoge(new Context(),"The Title");
    ProgressDialogUtils.showDialog();
  } 

  private void anotherMethod(){
    ProgressDialogUtils.createProgressDialoge(new Context(),"The other Title");
     ProgressDialogUtils.showDialog();
  }  
}
```

delete this two methods from your utility class and let the user invoke the respective methods in the instance returnd by the first method.

Comment: Correct dissmisProgress() and showProgress() method is redundant. Is it  good to use a static object to create an instance ?

Comment: @QuokMoon *"Is it good to use a static object to create an instance ?"* I for myself avoid static methods at any chance but this is a corner case since the `new` operator itself is also kinda static method call. on the other hand if you use non static methods you could later replace this util class with mocks for unittesting...